# Subir imagenes a un album en imgBB

Tags: javascript, api

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var settings = {
  "url": `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload?key=MI_API_KEY`,
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "processData": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "contentType": false,
  "data": form
};
```

Aquí lo que se hace es subir la iamgen directamente en "la página principal" tengo un album llamado "memorias" y necesito subir las foto ahí, he intentado esto:

```
"url": `https://api.imgbb.com/1/memorias/upload?key=MI_API_KEY`
```

Y no funciona, también probé:

```
"url": `https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload/memorias?key=MI_API_KEY`
```

Pero tampoco funciona, si alguien ha usado la API o sabe como puedo solucionar este problema agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: Hola, faltan algunos datos para que se te pueda ayudar. ¿Cómo haces la *request*, con `fetch` o con `ajax`? De primera vista, no veo bien que pongas el `timeout` a `0`. La petición nunca va a ser inmediata, por lo que debería ser un número más alto o sin especificar. Por otro lado, no creo que `contentType` admita un `boolean` por valor...